# MongoDB secondary replica set sync failure with Primary (in the reporting replica)

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

In the mongoDB secondary replica (reporting) I am getting the sync failure and also below error messages after 30 Hrs of the traffic run.

2020-07-15T01:50:29.987+0000 W EXECUTOR [conn408277] Terminating session due to error: InternalError: failed to create service entry worker thread
2020-07-15T01:50:31.656+0000 I -        [listener] pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Can anyone help on how to debug & fix the issue please

Comment: `pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable` would seem to imply some system resource was either limited or exhausted.   Some common possibilities include locked memory, open files, maps, number of processes, etc.

Comment: Exceeding process limit would do that, with the limit also applying to threads.

Comment: Is there any chance to limit the resource usage from the replica set configurations ?